# What to use instead of deprecated @ConfigPrefix("prefix") in quarkus

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus

I want to inject properties that have the same names but different prefixes in the application.properties file.
For example :

application.properties :

```
greeting.message = hello
bye.message = bye
```

For this, the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings) suggests the following usage:

```
@ConfigProperties(prefix = "greeting")
public class GreetingConfiguration {

    @Size(min = 20)
    public String message;

}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @Inject 
    GreetingConfiguration greetingConfiguration;

    @ConfigPrefix("bye") 
    GreetingConfiguration byeConfiguration;

}
```

This way I can call greetingConfiguration.message and byeConfiguration message using the same variable (message).

But it's use is not recommended because @ConfigProperties and @ConfigPrefix annotations are deprecated.

It is recommended to use @ConfigMapping instead.

Likewise, How can I use different prefixes and properties with the same name without creating more than one variable (ex :- message) on the java side?

Answer (score 2):

As per the document

> With config mappings it is possible to group multiple configuration
> properties in a single interface that share the same prefix. A config mapping requires an interface with minimal metadata configuration and annotated with the @io.smallrye.config.ConfigMapping annotation.

**Example(Same prefix),**

**application.properties**

```
message.greeting= hello
message.bye= bye
```

**Message Interface**

```
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.StaticInitSafe;
import io.smallrye.config.ConfigMapping;

@StaticInitSafe
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "message")
interface Message {
    String greeting();

    String bye();
}
```

**A config mapping interface can be injected into any CDI aware bean:**

```
@Path("/backend/api/v1")
public class BackEndSecretResource {

    @Inject
    Message message;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        return message.greeting() + message.bye();
    }
}
```

---

**This is not possible in the case of the same suffix because due to the below limitation.**

```
 @Experimental("ConfigMapping API to group configuration properties")
    public @interface ConfigMapping {
        /**
         * The prefix of the configuration properties.
         *
         * @return the configuration property prefix
         */
        String prefix() default "";
    
        NamingStrategy namingStrategy() default NamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE;
    
        enum NamingStrategy {
          
            VERBATIM,
          
            KEBAB_CASE,
          
            SNAKE_CASE
        }
    }
```

Means `String suffix()` unavailable. **Still, yours is a rare scenario, maybe you can figure out other ways.**

**Note *  @Experimental - Annotation that specifies that an element is experimental and may change without notice.**

Refer - https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings

Refer - https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/main/mapping/mapping.html

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. But it is really interesting that they deprecated such a nice feature

Comment: Asked the same here - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/22852

Comment: Still, yours is a rare scenario, maybe you can figure out other ways.

Comment: We're also wanting to use this (so not so rare anymore now). Example: we've got a (http) component configuration that we want to use in many other projects, but every time with another prefix.

So the common http config properties are grouped in an interface like this:

public interface HTTPConfiguration {
        String server();
        String path();
        int socketTimeout();
        String version();
        String authorization();
    }

And we wanted to use it like this:

    @ConfigMapping(prefix="ThisProjectName.http")
     HTTPConfiguration httpConfig;

etc